# How do I get the Date 5 Months from Now in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I get the Date 5 Months from Now in access

Comment: How do you define "5 months from now"? @Andomar's DateAdd() solution is the usual way, but it won't necessarily correspond 100% to a human or business definition of "5 months from now".

Answer (score 3):

Access has a DateAdd function:

```
DateAdd ("m", 5, Now())
```

Comment: There is no reason to use Now() if you're operating on dates only. Use Date() in all cases unless you actually need the time component returned by Now(). Given that running DateAdd ("m", 5, Now()) will not return the same result if you run it five minutes from now, but DateAdd ("m", 5, Date()) *will* give you the same result (unless midnight passed in between the two calls), I can't see any justification for using Now() in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Take Andomar's answer, but here is a dumber solution:

```
Future: Date()+((365/12)*5)
```

The result is somewhat different, and I post it only in case the result is somehow closer to what you need.

Comment: Either ignorance or carelessness ... darn it, I think it's carelessness.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What a terrible suggestion. Its results don't correspond to the calendar or to any human definition of "5 months".